# Small Sample of Clickstream data

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a sample of web traffic or click stream data set, please let me know sources from where I can get the sample data?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe check out this dataset on Quandl from Singularity? 
https://www.quandl.com/data/SNGLRTY/INTERNET_DATA_TRAFFIC-Internet-Data-Traffic

The original source of the dataset is: http://www.singularity.com/charts/page80.html

Hope this helps you get started.

[Disclosure: I work for Quandl]